# CakePHP Email changing from address on SMTP

Tags: email, cakephp-2.x

I have this email config to send via SMTP through our Google Apps Business Account.

```
class EmailConfig {
    public $default = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'myemail@mygmaildomain.com',
        'password' => 'secret_password',
        'transport' => 'Smtp'
    );
}
```

When I send an email doing this:

```
$email = new CakeEmail('default');
$email->from('no-reply@mygmaildomain.com', 'My App');
$email->to(array('recipient@mygmaildomain.com' => 'Recipient Name'));
$email->subject('Test Email');
$email->emailFormat('html');
$email->send();
```

The email gets delivered, but it sends the mail from: `myemail@mygmaildomain.com` and not `no-reply@mygmaildomain.com`.

Is there another setting that I need to use or is this not possible?

EDIT:

I've tried the solution provided in the comment below, however it still doesn't make the email come from `no-reply`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite or set the Return-Path in cakePHP Email Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156716/how-to-rewrite-or-set-the-return-path-in-cakephp-email-component). See the [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176653/3144159)

Comment: @InigoFlores that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the part in which you mentioned Google as your SMTP provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Google's SMTP server, the `from` header is ignored.

```
$email->from('no-reply@mygmaildomain.com', 'My App'); //Ignored by Gmail
```

From DigitalOcean's tutorial [How to use Google's SMTP server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server):

> NOTE: **Google automatically rewrites the From line** of any email you send via its SMTP server to the default Send mail as email address in your Gmail or Google Apps email account Settings. You need to be aware of this nuance because it affects the presentation of your email, from the point of view of the recepient, and it may also affect the Reply-To setting of some programs.

For this to work, you have to modify your mail settings in your Google Apps control panel:

> Workaround: In your Google email Settings, go to the Accounts tab/section and **make "default" an account other than your Gmail/Google Apps account**. This will cause Google's SMTP server to re-write the From field with whatever address you enabled as the default Send mail as address.